# Return values with reference arguments or by structure

Tags: vb.net, reference, arguments

In what situtations is it best to use reference arguments to return values?

```
Sub Example(byref value as integer)
  value = 3
End Sub
```

In what situations is it best to return the value (perhaps in a structure for more complex types)?

```
Function Example() as integer
  return 3
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, I'd avoid using reference arguments to return values.

THe design guidelines suggest avoiding this, which is why the Microsoft code analysis tools warn you when they find it.[Do not pass types by reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182146.aspx)

It's nearly always more maintainable to return values instead of passing arguments by reference, unless there is a very specific need to do so.  If you're generating a new value, return it.

Comment: +1 - returning a value through a parameter is never intuitive, it always requires a double-take to realize how the call is working

Answer (score 1):

when you want to return a state or status of an operation plus the result from the operation.

think of TryParse..it returns a conversion result as true or false and it returns the converted value by a ref variable.

```
 Dim number As Integer
 Dim result As Boolean = Int32.TryParse(value, number)


Public Shared Function TryParse ( _
    s As String, _
    <OutAttribute> ByRef result As Integer _
) As Boolean
```

but other than that, as others suggested i would not use by ref a lot, it can make code very hard to read and debug.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what the function's doing.  Generally, though, if there's only one return, by value is easier for the caller.  They can simply do:

```
int foo = Example(foo)
```

or:

```
int modifiedFoo = Example(foo)
```

as they prefer.