# Function return string or boolean

Tags: vb.net, string, winforms, function, boolean

I want a function to return a String or Boolean. Something like this:

```
Public Function GetString(Byval What As String) 'As... someting?
    If (What = "A") Then
        Return "String to return"
    Else if (What = "B") Then
        Return True
    End If

    Return False 'Nothing to return
End Function
```

How can i now do this? If i ask like

```
If GetString("A") Then
    MsgBox(GetString())
End IF
```

...it returns a string and of course it gives an error on converting string to bool.
I could always return strings and checks it lengths, but it feels bad. Or maybe I'm just into PHP too much?

But is there a way to do it more like this? If i ask for "B" i know it would return a bool, if i ask for "A" i want to alert the string if there was any and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can i now do this?

You can't.

A function can only return one type, not multiple.

You can return a custom type that contains a string and a boolean.

Comment: Nice and simple explanation! There is really no way to make a function return multiple types in VB? :)

Comment: @gubbfett - There is no way to do it in most languages.

Comment: You can actually though I don't recommend it.

Comment: @Ciarán - The return type from your function is `object`. That's not two different return types.

Comment: Yes, but an Object can be a String or a Boolean, so while strictly speaking it returns an object the object can have 2 types.

Comment: And as you say you could return 2 pieces of information in a Structure as well. This would be better than an object as it saves all that messy checking of the return type, so you can do it. Saying `You can't` is not true.

Comment: @Ciarán - Object can be a String or a Boolean or **anything**. The return type is still `Object` - not `Object` or something else. As for returning a custom type - yes, I did mention that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an Array list. You can store whatever type you need in the list and then parse it on the return. This is really not best practice as explained above, but when you gotta get things done... The end justifies the means. Not recommended.

```
Public Function GetString(Byval What As String) As ArrayList
Dim b as boolean = True 
dim myArrayList as Arraylist = New ArrayList

    If (What = "A") Then
        ArrayList.Add("String to return")
    Else if (What = "B") Then
        ArrayList.Add(b)
    End If

    Return False 'Nothing to return
End Function
```

**Proof of concept below:**

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim a As Boolean = True
        Dim myarraylist As ArrayList = New ArrayList

        myarraylist.Add(a)
        myarraylist.Add("g")

        Debug.WriteLine(myarraylist.GetType.ToString)
        Debug.WriteLine(myarraylist(0).GetType.ToString)
        Debug.WriteLine(myarraylist(1).GetType.ToString)

        If myarraylist(0).GetType.ToString = "System.string" Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Function returned a String")
        ElseIf myarraylist(0).GetType.ToString = "System.boolean" Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Function returned a Boolean")
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return `Object`, but it is considered very bad form for a function to return 2 data types.

Comment: @gubbfett - Because then you need to check what type was returned and convert to it. It is both error prone and adds complexity.

Comment: It is difficult to debug for a start E.g. `If GetString("A") Then` will fail. But more importantly it implies that the function is performing 2 tasks which should be in 2 separate functions. A function should only return one piece of information or if you want to return 2 then consider using a Structure.

Answer (score 0):

As [Oded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13878425/467172) said, you can't return more than one parameter from a function.

It is not too clear what you are doing from your code example, but you may look into [passing parameters by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1107133/467172). As pointed out in the answer there, passing a parameter by reference is useful for:

> when you want to return a state or status of an operation plus the result from the operation.

This is how [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and similar methods work.